# Is it safe to use hot glue in electronics?

Tags: electrostatic

I know question seems too basic to ask but I couldn't find any specific information anywhere .

I want to use hot glue gun to stick components and cables into cardboard to prevent them move or break but someone said hot glue is electrostatic and it'll cause problem.

So can I use it or should I switch to alternative ways ?

Circuits I'm talking about MOSFETs or IC circuits and hot glue will directly touch into pins.

Comment: the plugs on many moulded data cables are filled with hot glue.

Comment: We do not Know how good it is at high electric fields ?  Mains ? what about RF ?

Comment: The following answers of mine may be of use generally: [Aleph](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18533/3288) & [Beth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/38766/3288) & [Gimmel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/32812/3288)

Comment: For hobbyist sure, in a commercial application, it's going to be dependent on the exact specifications of the hot glue. For instance if there's any sulfur present that can be a disaster for solder joints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hot-melt glue won't cause problems directly, but it also has no static-dissipative properties (good insulator), so it won't prevent problems, either.

It's great for sticking things down when building prototypes, but I certainly wouldn't use it in any sort of production environment — there are far better choices.

You probably do want to make some effort to keep it off the pins of your devices anyway, because if you subsequently need to (re)solder those pins, the high temperature of the soldering iron will either melt or break down the glue, creating a bit of a mess.

Comment: Thanks for answer . Just to be sure , MOSFETs are tend to use everything as ground (like if you touch gate pin MOSFET can close the circuit ) Can MOSFET use hot glue as ground ? I'm afraid hot glue act as capacitor and disturb the MOSFET

Comment: I don't understand the question. As I said, hot glue is a good insulator, so it has no electrical function at all -- ground or otherwise. Its dielectric constant is undoubtedly higher than air, so yes, it would increase parasitic capacitance a bit -- but not significantly compared to the gate capacitance of the MOSFET itself. But it's another good reason to keep the glue off the pins.

Comment: I'm sorry, my English not good enough to explain it properly. I mean hot glue is good insulator but if I remember right, it can hold charge. That charge can effect the MOSFET ?

Comment: I don't see how. Unless you're doing something unusual, all of the other nodes in your circuit will have much lower impedance than the effective impedance of the hot glue.

Answer (score 2):

Dave means it is both a good electrical and thermal insulator so local heating will melt it and not a great adhesive if running hot.

Use Polyurethane if you need it.

PLastic will hold a charge, but will sync more current than air for Miller Capacitance but not as much as the semiconductor internal Miller Gate capacitance

Not useful in industry but if cold OK  for a prototype.

ONLY PU or polyurethane is used for structural THT.

Plastic has some relative dielectric constant of about 3 to 4 x air. for crosstalk capacitance, but the electrode gap wide/gap determines that value per unit length.

Comment: My question was about cold prototypes so thanks for answer. Also I'm using high temp red RTV silicone for that prototypes but it takes a lot of time to dry.

Answer (score 0):

I used the stuff as a board coating in years past, even in production.  Better than anything I've ever seen.  Fast "drying", very low leakage, cheap, no noxious outgassing.