# What is the name of the translucent substance on the PCB?

Tags: pcb, keyboard

PCB on photo is from the Kinesis Advantage keyboard. I need a similar substance to remount the PCB. What substance should I use?

[image: PCB with translucent substance from a kinesis advantage keyboard]

Comment: It's just glue. Looks a bit like the cheap molten glue I used to stick my shoes back together.

Comment: I agree with @user253751 . It looks like glue to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like hot melt adhesive, i.e. glue.

Comment: Does it matter if you use high temp or low temp glue?  I'm guessing you'd want low temp for most applications?

Comment: @KH, I read somewhere that high temperature hot melt glue can damage insulation.

Comment: @mihail-haritonov thank you.  I always see a variety of goos used for mechanical support or thermal protection or as I recently learned as mechanical protection and isolation for a bare die chip.  I figure if I need one I'll probably go with hot glue or try to find a silicone that doesn't wreck electronics, but now at least I know Dad's industrial glue gun is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @KH, in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18533/144719 helpful answer author recommends neutral cure silicone rubber (Dow Corning 839, for example, if I understood correctly the comments on the answer) instead of hot melt glue.

Comment: @mihail-haritonov thank you that's golden.